# Interpret the inequality geometrically $\left|\sin{x}-\sin{y}\right| \le \left|x-y\right|$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry

> Interpret the inequality geometrically $\left|\sin{x}-\sin{y}\right| \le \left|x-y\right|$.

It is possible to prove the inequality through Lagrange's Theorem, there are several proofs here, but that's not what I'm looking for. What I'm looking for is a geometric interpretation. I started by thinking about areas of rectangles or triangles, but without any conclusions. Can you give me some help?

Comment: I agree with the answer of Just a User, that you can compare arc length between two points, versus the difference in *heights* (i.e. distance from the $x$-axis).  However, there is a subtlety here: I was taught that the sine and cosine functions are not actually defined geometrically, on the unit circle.  Instead, they are defined as satisfying a set of axioms.  Then, the Math book's author demonstrates that the Analytical Geometry def of the sine and cosine functions happens to satisfy the axioms, as long as the functions' domains are changed from angles to real numbers (i.e. arc lengths).

Comment: There are many definitions possible depending on the context. I believe answer of Just a user is correct for any real $x$ and $y$ except last sentence: "the arc distance which would be not greater than $|x-y|$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity, let's assume $0<x<y<\pi/2$, and consider the distance between the two points on the unit circle $X=(\cos(x), \sin(x))$ and $Y=(\cos(y),\sin(y))$. Then we have $$|\sin(x)-\sin(y)|\le d(X, Y)\le |x-y|$$

The second inequality is due to the straight-line distance between $X$ and $Y$ is smaller than the arc distance which would be $y-x$.